# how to recognize start and end of rotation gesture in iOS?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I need two functions which would be fired when the rotation gesture starts and finishes, because I need to know the whole angle of the rotation. Currently the gesture recogniser is fired all the time until the rotation finishes, and I cannot find out when it has finished, to find to total angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the method you hook to your gesture gets called for all of the gestures states, like began/ended/canceled/changed. You can however ask the gesture for its current state within the method, and add specific functionality for these different states. Here's a basic example:

```
- (void)rotationGestureHandler:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // do stuff - call method for gesture began
    }else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // do other stuff - call method for gesture ended
    }
}
```

Comment: this link is also nice: http://rogchap.com/2011/06/10/ios-image-manipulation-with-uigesturerecognizer-scale-move-rotate/